# SELECT statement - add another derived field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has 3 columns. `Name`,`DateOfBirth`, `DateDeceded`. The fields `DateOfBirth` and `DateDeceded` have the data type `DATE`.

Now when i do a `Select * from TableName`. I want to display the Name, date of birth, date deceded and the number of years the person lived (`DateDeceded` - `DateOfBirth`).

How do i write the SQL Select statement to include the `NumberOfYearsLived` field ?

Comment: Which RDBMS (e.g. MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server) are you using? It might make a difference.

Comment: Oh, duh - it's tagged MySQL. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT Name,
       DateOfBirth,
       DateDeceded,
       YEAR(DateDeceded) - YEAR(DateOfBirth) AS NumberOfYearsLived
  FROM TableName
```

Edit: you might want to try this instead. It might be more accurate.

```
SELECT Name,
       DateOfBirth,
       DateDeceded,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DateDeceded, DateofBirth) AS NumberOfYearsLived
  FROM TableName
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: Just a tip: for and accurate result you have to check if the month of death is less than month of birth.

Comment: Is it a must to add the name of the fields (`name`,`dateofbirth`) ? Can't i just use `*` instead ?

Comment: Good point. I might add another query that returns a more accurate result.

Comment: No, you can just use `*` if you want.

Comment: How will the query be when i use `*` ? `SELECT *,YEAR(DateDeceded) - YEAR(DateOfBirth) AS NumberOfYearsLived` ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use `*, derivedField`.

Comment: How will the query be? Just like you wrote it right there, except including `FROM TableName` at the end.

Comment: `YEAR` is a MySQL function. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year